# Escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos y textos con menos ruido

Tags: discusión

Últimamente me estoy fijando en que muchas preguntas contienen títulos del tipo "*help me with X*" o "*¿alguien sabe por qué Y?*", etc.

Creo que debemos mejorar esta parte: el espacio del título es muy reducido y todo lo que no es imprescindible, acaba siendo ruido. Para mí, sobra, vaya.

Algún ejemplos serían [¿Alguien me podría ayudar a identificar el tipo de oración por favor?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/15574/revisions) o [No llores por mi Argentina. Help with lyrics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15710/1674).

Por ello, estoy buscando las versiones más "sangrantes" y editando el título para ceñirlo a la pregunta en sí.

Si alguien tiene también ganas, puede buscar palabras como "help", "ayuda", etc in las preguntas (truco: escribid `is:q "help"` para filtrar las preguntas, donde `q` quiere decir question):

- [Help](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20help)

---

Si ya que estáis queréis hacer una revisión más extensa, podéis eliminar todo el ruido añadido del tipo:

- Hola, soy nuevo...
- Esta es mi primera pregunta...
- Muchas gracias
- Edito: he pensado que...

etc.

Para más información, podéis leer el debate [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/209901). Al fin y al cabo, la idea es clara: todo lo que no sea pregunta en sí es espacio y tiempo [fuera de ámbito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13199/1674) que no aporta nada relevante en muchos casos.

<strike>¡Muchas gracias a todos!</strike> Es broma ;-)

Comment: ¿Tenemos que continuar la lucha ahora (en 2020)?

Comment: @mdewey la lucha nunca termina (_Don't give up without a fight_, decía Pink Floyd :D)

Answer (score 1):

Hay veces en las que no tengo muy clara la pregunta que voy a hacer hasta que termino el razonamiento previo. En esos casos, prefiero darle a la pregunta un título introductorio que da una idea de por dónde van a ir los tiros, y que "pique" un poco a la gente a entrar a leer. Es el caso de mi última pregunta titulada *[Sólo estar durmiendo es mejor que estar domido](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18064/12637)*.

Sí, es verdad, la pregunta no está en el título, pero sí está en negrita en el cuerpo de la pregunta para que la gente la visualice rápidamente incluso sin leer el texto previo. ¿Es esto una mala práctica? A veces los títulos me salen así un poco por vena artística...

Comment: Buenas Carlos, a mí no me convence y no creo que sea buena práctica. En la mayoría de los casos, yo pongo el título después de escribir el cuerpo de la pregunta, pues como bien describes el propio redactado y búsqueda de recursos acaba llevando la pregunta por unos derroteros a veces no previstos. Como sitio de preguntas/respuestas que es esto, considero recomendable escribir títulos que lo sean. De lo contrario, nos desviamos hacia otros formatos tipo blog. Interesante referencia (canónica): [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/209901).