# Can we have [concordancia] and [agreement] point to [concordancia-gramatical]?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

We currently have the [concordancia-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia-gramatical).  It would be helpful to have [concordancia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia) and [agreement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agreement) as synonyms.  Apparently I can't set up the synonym relationship.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get a browser. In the meanwhile, do not add both of them, since it won't add any value

Comment: @fedorqui - No hurry and thanks.  I wonder if "concordancia-gramatical" could be shortened to "concordancia."

Answer (score 1):

I just added the synonym [agreement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agreement), which now maps to [concordancia-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia-gramatical).

Regarding [concordancia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia), note that we also have [concordancia-verbal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia-verbal), so we firstly should clarify when and how to use those [tag:concordancia-*]. I would personally go for removing [concordancia-verbal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia-verbal) and tagging those with [concordancia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordancia) + [verbos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbos). Let's comment on it.

Comment: I like your proposed solution -- narrow down a general concordancia tag with an additional tag such as verbos or adjetivos.

Comment: Re https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/subject-verb-agreement-repitiendo-y-determinando-ilustra?noredirect=1#comment42236_3995 -- are you saying you want me to go ahead and start making those changes?  I hesitate to swamp the active list with too many tag changes at a time.  What do you think would be best?

Comment: @aparente001 I am saying let's wait and see if others express their point of views. Interesting to check the discussion in [Maximum number of edits at one time?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2853/1674): we are a small community and so many edits will indeed swamp the active list.

Comment: @fedorque - I was trying not to add "concordancia-gramatical" to all the agreement questions in one sitting. // Are you saying I should wait before replacing "concordancia-verbal" with "concordancia" plus "verbos"?  Or are you saying I should not yet start adding any concordancia tags yet at all?  I thought you meant the former but now I'm not sure....

Comment: @aparente001 I am saying that let's not retag so much in one sitting and wait a bit to have more opinions in Meta before going on and doing things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it.  Are you saying (A) I should wait before replacing "concordancia-verbal" with "concordancia" plus "verbos"? Or are you saying (B) I should not yet start adding any concordancia tags yet at all?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: I am saying A).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Whew!  We have no disagreement about this.  I have not touched the questions tagged with "concordancia-verbal" and have no intention of doing so in the near future.  So, it looks like we're good on this score.

Comment: @aparente001 then why did you [start doing it again](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/19211/revisions)?.

Comment: I didn't replace "concordancia-verbal" with "concordancia."   Isn't that what (A) says?  I'm totally lost, now, fedorqui, I do not understand what's bothering you.  I'm starting to get that feeling you get when you try to make breakfast in *someone else's kitchen* and when your weekend host comes in and you realize from their body language that they really don't want anyone else doing *anything* in their kitchen.  But I've checked what SE Meta has to say about best practices regarding tags, and I checked explicitly with you.  You clarified that you meant (A).  I just don't get it.