# What is the functional limit of Meta questions per day here?

Tags: discusión, soporte, preguntas, meta

Every SE site has its own character.  That is all well and good.

I asked three questions at Meta on April 9 and another on April 10 and apparently overloaded the system by asking four questions in quick succession (see [Let's clarify the tag "escritura"](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/lets-clarify-the-tag-escritura#comment5002_2898); and two comments at another thread, starting with [We have a "lo" tag but no "le" tag](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/we-have-a-lo-tag-but-no-le-tag#comment5015_2902)).  This was not my intention and I would like to understand the expectations here better, to avoid doing this again in future.  Could a rule of thumb be provided, please, as to what functional daily or weekly limit I should try to keep within?  In other words, what question frequency still feels comfortable, without it feeling like I'm *overparticipating*?

Comment: Creating a synonym does not need a workflow: it is as direct as you had them done [recently](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2893/1674), since it just needs one minute of mod time. You can ask 10 questions per day about these if you wish, they are not a problem. They are _requests_. What I have unsuccessfully tried to explain these days is that bringing up so many broader _debates_ in so little time is counter-productive: no one is participating and Meta is starting to be tiring. Better one debate → consensus and then start with a brand new topic. I won't be commenting again.

Comment: @fedorqui - Are you suggesting that a request that you feel requires no debate, such as "Can we have [concordancia] and [agreement] point to [concordancia-gramatical]?", is less of a strain on the system than (not sure what question to point to as an example of a PITA question)?  Look, take your time with this -- but at some point, an answer that provides guidance and helps me understand would go far to steering me in the direction you want me to go.

Comment: If you look at the users of this meta site you will see that we are few. I read articles and vote on simple questions but debates tend to pass me by so if your aim is a wide-ranging discussion I think you do need to hold back your enthusiasm. Perhaps experiment with reducing to one a week and see if you get a richer response and then either increase or decrease the flow depending on the result?

Comment: @mdewey - For the most part I'm trying to do tag housekeeping.  It seems that ordinary mortals are rather limited in what they can do in this realm without moderator assistance. Frankly, when I feel sure of the change I want to make, I'd like to be able to get started with it on my own, but the system doesn't provide very well for this.  At times, the moderators have hesitated to go ahead with a proposed or requested change, preferring to wait several weeks for community discussion.  I'm going to look up an example, give me a moment.

Comment: @mdewey - I couldn't find it.  Sigh.

Comment: To clarify fedorqui's point, in the span of roughly one month (since Feb 26) you have created around 17 questions, which received a total of  14 answers: 3 of them are your own answers, 10 come from the moderation team and 1 comes from another user. That is an indication that you're not engaging the community successfully in a discussion that they find interesting and productive to improve the site. Fedorqui has been warning you and trying to help you about that (most recently [here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2902/5481)), but as usual you ignored/challenged moderator's feedback

Comment: @aparente001 `It seems that ordinary mortals are rather limited in what they can do in this realm without moderator assistance`. I disagree. High level users are undistinguishable from mods regarding abilities to make changes. The mechanism of the stacks rewards you with more [power to improve the stack](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) as you earn the trust and support of you peers, but you also need to understand the community's pulse and engage them successfully. Fedorqui has been trying to help you w/ this, but you keep disregarding his advice. **Please, listen to him**.